# Integration testing running HTTP server instance without mocking?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I have been implementing CI on a legacy project that has very little junit test coverage.  I have explained that given where we are that the quickest bang for buck is to deploy and run up the code as part of the weekly build and then hit the running Tomcat instance with a number of HTTP requests.  Planning on doing this via JUnit.

Tests will be basic, but cover.

1. Has server started and can it process HTTP requests.
2. Are we getting the expected data back from the server.
   ...

I appreciate that this isn't ideal, but at present there are no tests which enable the dev team to deduce whether the weekly build is good and actually runs.

All of the examples I have found to date seem to mock the actual HTTP request.  Is there a framework out there that will provide the functionality to handle http requests and the blocking async results checking?

Comment: you need a self hosting middleware like owin for microsoft asp.net. i don't know if the same exists for java. And this will imply to change some code in the way your application starts. hope it helps you.

Comment: Is it a UI (HTML) or Web Service testing (REST, SOAP)?

Comment: I am not interested in testing the UI.  I am just after a simple framework that provides the ability to make http requests and then check the expected results.  Even just checking that the server returned a code 200 is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can automate a browser with various tools.

A common one is [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) web browser. We couple this with BDD testing/cucumber/specflow for regression and CI.

Others include [robot](http://robotframework.org)

For tools rather than a framework, you could use badboy, jmeter or grinder

Comment: none of the tools i have suggested require access to the source code. We use them to test COTS products

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter could be used with some validations, though it's really a performance testing tool.  Why not curl or wget?

Answer (score 0):

Decided that using SpringJunit4ClassRunner and autowiring the required dependencies in each of the test cases makes it simple to create isolated integration tests.